# Accessing C# dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a color dictionary as shown below.

```
Dictionary<string, List<System.Drawing.Color>> channelColorInformation = 
    new Dictionary<string, List<System.Drawing.Color>>();

List<System.Drawing.Color> colorInfo = new List<System.Drawing.Color>();

System.Drawing.Color color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFF0F8FF");
colorInfo.Add(color);
color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFFAEBD7");
colorInfo.Add(color);
color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FF00FFFF");
colorInfo.Add(color);
channelColorInformation.Add("Channel1", colorInfo);
```

How do I get the `System.Drawing.Color` information from the dictionary for `Channel1` at index 0, 1, 2?

Comment: There is no order guarantee. Use OrderedDictionary. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.aspx

Comment: @asawyer: There's guaranteed order within the *list*, which is what's fetched from the dictoinary.

Comment: @asawyer The indexed part would apply to the List so a regular dictionary would be fine.

Comment: @JonSkeet Ah, I read it as wanting to index the dictionary. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
List<Color> listForChannel1 = channelColorInformation["Channel1"];
Color c1 = listForChannel1[0];    
Color c2 = listForChannel1[2];    
Color c3 = listForChannel1[3];
```

**UPDATE**

@Jon's answer is also relevant because it shows two options for dealing with the possibility that the key is not present in the dictionary.

Comment: I did fetch the dictionary value by key.  The value is in turn a list, which can be accessed by indexer.

Answer (score 3):

There are two different options, depending on whether it's an error for the entry to be missing from the dictionary. If that represents a bug, you can fetch it with the indexer:

```
List<Color> colors = channelColorInformation["Channel1"];
// Access the list in the normal way... either with an indexer (colors[0])
// or using foreach
```

This will throw an exception if there's no entry for the key "Channel1".

Otherwise, use [`TryGetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013.aspx):

```
List<Color> colors;
if (channelColorInformation.TryGetValue("Channel1", out colors))
{
    // Use the list here
}
else
{
    // No entry for the key "Channel1" - take appropriate action
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = channelColorInformation["Channel1"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Each list element is a `List<Color>` instance, so you can use the [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ebtbkkc.aspx) to access the single items:

```
List<Color> channel = channelColorInformation["Channel1"];
Color index0 = channel[0];
Color index1 = channel[1];
// etc.
```